# eval inside gsubfn inside sub function: object not found

Tags: r, function, eval

Give the two functions

```
subfun <- function(txt) 
  gsubfn::gsubfn("§([^§]+)§", ~eval(parse(text=x)), txt)

topfun <- function(id = 1L) 
  subfun("Hello §id§ world!")
```

The following **(1.)** should yield `"Hello 1 world!"`but throws an error instead:

```
topfun() 
# Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'id' not found
```

These two (2.) & (3.) work as expected:

```
id <- 2L
topfun()
# [1] "Hello 2 world!"

topfun2 <- function(id = 1L) 
  gsubfn::gsubfn("§([^§]+)§", ~eval(parse(text=x)), "Hello §id§ world!")
topfun2() 
# [1] "Hello 1 world!"
```

**How can I make (1.) work?**

I tried several `environment()` and `parent.frame()` variations with the `envir` parameter of `eval` and `gsubfn`, including passing `topfun`'s environment to `subfun` via the ellipsis argument. All to no success. (Not that I had greater knowledge of what's going on under the hood. But I would have expected R to go up one parent environment after another to look for `id`...)

I'm using `R version 3.3.0` and `gsubfn` package version `0.6.6`.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am no expert at this but the problem seems to be the use of a formula as `replacement` in `gsubfun`. At least I am unable to pass an environment to `eval` if it is in a formula.

```
subfun_2 <- function(txt){
  ev <- parent.frame() # the environment in which subfun_2 was called
  gsubfn::gsubfn("§([^§]+)§", ~eval(parse(text=x), envir = ev), txt)
}
topfun_2 <- function(id = 1L) subfun_2("Hello §id§ world!")
topfun_2()
# Error in eval(parse(text = x), envir = ev) : 
#  argument "ev" is missing, with no default
```

If you use a function instead it works as expected:

```
subfun_3 <- function(txt){
   ev <- parent.frame() 
   gsubfn::gsubfn("§([^§]+)§", function(x)eval(parse(text=x), envir = ev), txt)
}
topfun_3 <- function(id = 1L) subfun_3("Hello §id§ world!")
topfun_3()
# Hello 1 world!
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Gabor makes a note in `?gsubfn` on formula usage and environments ( _"If replacement is a formula instead of a function  (...) [t]he environment of the function is the environment of the formula"_ ). Dunno what it means, but I assumed it doesn't not make a big difference. Anyways, I go on with your function.